# Way to do "Any" on an aggregation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three fields that are always tied together (is there a proper term for this?), such as:

`table`

- [other fields]
- country_name (United States)
- country_iso2 (US)
- country_iso3 (USA)

In other words, whenever I have the value of one I have the value of all thre (as if the country would be a FK to another table).

In SQL Server, this would verbosely be done by doing something like:

```
SELECT country_name, country_iso2, country_iso3 FROM table
GROUP BY country_name, country_iso2, country_iso3
```

Is there a way where I can only group on one (instead of three) and still get the same values? Something like:

```
SELECT country_name, country_iso2, country_iso3 FROM table
GROUP BY country_name
```

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh got it, thanks: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65609/column-vs-field-have-i-been-using-these-terms-incorrectly

Comment: And the shortest explanation is perhaps the best: "_a single column could have multiple fields (inside a record)_"  a_horse_with_no_name Jun 22 '17 at 13:14_

Comment: Also, a date column consists of a year field, a month field and a day field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name, country_iso2, country_iso3
FROM table;
```

This eliminates the need for the `GROUP BY`.

Alternatively, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT country_name, MAX(country_iso2), MAX(country_iso3)
FROM table
GROUP BY country_name
```

This has the nice property that if any of the ISO codes happen to be `NULL`, then only the actual value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

How about `select distinct`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name, country_iso2, country_iso3 
FROM table
```